# fullcalendar.io : jsonfeed is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to load JSON data using jsonfeed as displayed blow.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: '/myfeed.php'
});
```

I am getting JSON data but it is not getting displayed on Calendar. Blow is JSON data.

```
{
  "events": [
    {
      "start": "2017-04-25",
      "title": "Event1"
    },
    {
      "start": "2017-04-26",
      "title": "Event2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Also I am unable to get any nice tutorial on it. It will be much better if tutorial is also provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your JSON file does not have '**end**' field, it would only pass through '**allDay**' events. I have tested this on my site. Also, keep in mind that FullCalendar nulls out **end** field if it is the same as **start** field to reduce the amount of data that is pushed to FullCalendar if you are using the **utils.php** file.

If that does not help, you would also want to check the format of the text. I have noticed that FullCalendar likes **UTF-8** format. In the myFeed.php, make sure to convert the text before decoding the file:

```
$json = mb_convert_encoding($json, 'UTF-8',mb_detect_encoding($json, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
$input_arrays = json_decode($json, true);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

When you call events as a json field:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: '/myfeed.php'
});
```

Here is a URL that FullCalendar might visit:

```
/myfeed.php?start=2013-12-01&end=2014-01-12&_=1386054751381
```

But, in your json file, there is no field named **end**. Try adding it.

Also, there are other ways you can find [here](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/#caching) to get the JSON value from file.